# How to find/generate nightly documentation?

Tags: rust, documentation

How should I go about finding documentation for crates in nightly Rust? Recently I've been working with the `syntax` crate, and the only place I've found for up-to-date documentation is [a GitHub page that someone has put up](https://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/index.html). I'd rather rely on an official resource, or a way of generating the docs myself locally.

I've tried `rustup doc`, but that only generates docs for the standard library. I've also checked out docs.rs, but that seems to only generate docs for user crates, not crates like `syntax` and `rustc` (I'm not sure what "category" of crates these fall under, as they're neither in the std lib or developer-created crates).

Comment: Have you tried fetching the source code from [rust-lang/rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) and running `cargo doc`?

Answer (score 2):

Considering that [manishearth's documentation](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/rustc/) is listed in the [`CONTRINUTING.md`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/81734e0e06d24cf580dd5352c64d10110e4d3b7b/CONTRIBUTING.md#helpful-links-and-information) file, I'd say it is a pretty official resource.

As for generating it yourself, I haven't done it myself since they switched to `x.py`, but they also list

```
compiler-docs = true
```

in the [configuration section](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/81734e0e06d24cf580dd5352c64d10110e4d3b7b/CONTRIBUTING.md#configuration). I'd say that plus either `python x.py build` or `python x.py doc` should suffice. Note that this will take some time!